# Getting the 0 value after dividing the int values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to divide the two int values, but after dividing them I am getting only one value which is 0.
Following is my formula:

`int RH=(A1/M1)*100(where A1=145 and M1=199)` where `RH` value should have 72 but I am getting 0, Can somebody please help me out?

Following is my code:

```
int RvalueH,RvalueV,RvalueT;
if((M1!=-1 || M1>0) && (M2!=-1 || M2>0) && (M3>0 || M3!=-1))
{
    int RH = (A1 / M1);
    int RV = A2 / M2;
    int RT = A3 / M3;
    RvalueH=RH*100;
    RvalueV=100*RV;
    RvalueT=100*RT;
}
```

Comment: What do you think the value of `RH` is? (Bear in mind that it's an `int`, and the result of integer division...) 145 / 199 is *not* 72.

Comment: But (145/199)*100=72 for int

Comment: You haven't read my comment carefully. You're multiplying RH by 100. What's the value of RH?

Comment: Or multiply by 100 *before* dividing by M1...

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, this is a common mistakes for new programmers who try to perform [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) when they actually meant (*or at least they think*) to use floating point division.

From [`/` Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx)

> When you divide two integers, the result is **always** an integer. For
>   example, the result of 7 / 3 is 2.

That's why when you calculate `145 / 199` result will be `0`, not `0,728643216080402` etc.

Instead of that, multiple your `145` with `100` *first* and *then* divide the result wit `199`. Since this *still* performs integer division, it disregards fractional part of the result and it will be `72` not `72,8643216080402` etc..

```
int A1 = 145, M1 = 199;
int RH = (A1 * 100) / M1; // RH will be 72
```

Comment: @AniketPanke Good to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your expression to get a non `0` result:

```
  int RH = 100 * A1 / M1;
  RvalueH = RH;
```

The same thing needs to be done for `RvalueV` and `RvalueT`.

The problem in your code is that `RH = (A1 / M1)` will yield `0` as it is a integer division. Multiplying by `100` first avoids the result becoming `0`.

Comment: No I want to multiply (A1/M1)*100...I cant rewrite like 100*A1/M1, but whtever it is also not working

Answer (score 0):

Use `double`, round to zero and then convert to `int`.

eg `var result = Convert.ToInt(Math.Round((double)R1/M1,0));`

By the way `M1>0` mean its always `M1 != -1` true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this you need to `convert` the values to `float` to get the exact answer.

You should store the returned value of division in `float` variable to allow number with `decimal points`. As `int` will not hold the values after `decimal point`.

```
float RvalueH,RvalueV,RvalueT;
int A1 = 145;
int M1 = 199;
float RH =  (float)A1 /(float) M1;
RvalueH = RH*100;
```